# How to return error code 'auth/email-already-exists' to client from cloud function?

Tags: firebase, error-handling, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function where I am doing some user registration but I cant get it to return error code 'auth/email-already-exists' if the email is already used for another user.

```
catch (error) {
    if (error.type === 'UnauthenticatedError') {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unauthenticated', error.message);
    } else if (error.type === 'NotAnAdminError' || error.type === 'InvalidRoleError') {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('failed-precondition', error.message);
    } else if (error.code === 'auth/email-already-exists') {          
        //return the error code here
    } else {
         throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', error.type); 
    }
}
```

I have tried returning `throw new functions.https.HttpsError('email exists', error);` but it keeps returning INTERNAL. I dont unterstand why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really pass arbitrary string values to the first parameter of [HttpsError()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_https_.httpserror#constructor).  The list of valid values can be found in the [API documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_https_#functionserrorcode).  These strings translate directly into HTTP error codes.  If you need a specific error, you will have to find the closes matcht (maybe "invalid-argument"? - you will have to decide), and add your own specific error message to it.

Note that throwing HttpsError only makes sense in a [callable function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable).  Since you didn't say what type of function you're writing, nor show the entire source code, I'm pointing this out in case you didn't know.